# display alert dont show

Tags: javascript, alert

My js error,

how to display "1 months" in alert

ori html :

```
<div class="left" style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;">1 months</div>
```

my js code :

```
var div = document.querySelector('[class="left"][style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;"]');

alert( div[0].innerHTML );
```

Comment: I don't think you can use the style attribute as a selector like that. And there should never be a reason to do so, either.

Comment: I don't understand the question.. 

what is wrong with: `alert("1 months");`

Your alert is fine the document.querySelector is returning an empty array and div[0].innerHTML is probably producing an error that `undefined is does not have the property innerHTML`

Comment: Note: `document.querySelector` returns null if no matches are found; otherwise, it returns the first matching element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your code like this

```
var div = document.querySelector('[class="left"][style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;"]');

alert( div.innerHTML );
```

or

```
var div = document.querySelectorAll('[class="left"][style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;"]');

alert( div[0].innerHTML );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your query selector.  To select the div by class name you can go with

```
var div = document.querySelector('.left');
```

If you have more than one element with the same class, I would recommend setting an id for the div.

```
<div id='IDNAME' class="left" style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;">1 months</div>
```

And you can query it like so:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#IDNAME');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('left').innerHTML);
```

Comment: not work, this work `alert(document.getElementsByClassName('left')[0].innerHTML);`

Answer (score 0):

```
just use alert( div.innerHTML ); instead of alert( div[0].innerHTML );

Also make sure that you call this after your div is rendered i.e like

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="left" style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;">1 months</div>
<script>
var div = document.querySelector('[class="left"][style="height:15px; width:128px; overflow:hidden;"]');

alert( div.innerHTML );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```